# geom_rect: background color repeated per season

Tags: r, ggplot2, rect, geom

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df<-data.frame(Category= c("a","b","a","b"), Value = c(25,90,40,10), Date= c("2016-02-13", "2016-05-13", "2016-08-13", "2016-11-13"))
```

In reality it is more complex, has several years and several observed objects so that it should be a faceted plot in the end, but I think this has nothing to do with the question.

I want to have a ggplot (line plot), where every season got it's own background color.
e.g.: spring from March to May in yellow,
summer from June to August in red
autumn from September to November in blue
and winter from December to February in grey.

This should be repeated, regardless the year as it goes through several years and the database will be updated with time.

I tried a lot with geom_rect but didn't find a working solution.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your goal correctly, I think you can achieve it by creating two additional variables, say `Season` and `Color` that correspond to `Date` column, and then supply the columns as necessary to `geom_line`.

To make the steps and the results clearer, I create a dummy data by expanding your data to another year (2017) with similar date and category but slightly different values:

### 1. The data

```
df<-data.frame(Category= c("a","b","a","b"), Value = c(25,90,40,10), Date= c("2016-02-13", "2016-05-13", "2016-08-13", "2016-11-13"))
df2<-data.frame(Category= c("a","b","a","b"), Value = c(30,95,45,15), Date= c("2017-02-13", "2017-05-13", "2017-08-13", "2017-11-13"))
dat <- rbind.data.frame(df,df2)

dat
  Category Value       Date
1        a    25 2016-02-13
2        b    90 2016-05-13
3        a    40 2016-08-13
4        b    10 2016-11-13
5        a    30 2017-02-13
6        b    95 2017-05-13
7        a    45 2017-08-13
8        b    15 2017-11-13
```

### 2. Creating `Season` and `Color` columns

```
dat.season <- dat %>% 
     mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>% 
     mutate(Month = months(Date)) %>% 
     mutate(Season = case_when(Month %in% c("March", "April", "May") ~ "spring",  
                               Month %in% c("June", "July", "August") ~ "summer", 
                               Month %in% c("September", "October", "November") ~ "autumn", 
                               Month %in% c("December", "January", "February")~ "winter")) %>% 
     mutate(Color = case_when(Season == "spring"~ "yellow", 
                              Season == "summer"~ "red", 
                              Season == "autumn"~ "blue", 
                              Season == "winter"~ "grey"))
dat.season
  Category Value       Date    Month Season  Color
1        a    25 2016-02-13 February winter   grey
2        b    90 2016-05-13      May spring yellow
3        a    40 2016-08-13   August summer    red
4        b    10 2016-11-13 November autumn   blue
5        a    30 2017-02-13 February winter   grey
6        b    95 2017-05-13      May spring yellow
7        a    45 2017-08-13   August summer    red
8        b    15 2017-11-13 November autumn   blue
```

### Supplying the columns to `geom_line()`

```
dat.season %>% ggplot() + 
  geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = Value), 
            colour = dat.season$Color) + 
  theme_bw()
```

#### The result

[image]

### Update to add coloured background

Here is the line plot along with coloured backgrounds for each season.

```
dat.season %>% 
    ggplot() + 
    geom_rect(aes(xmin = Date[1], xmax = Date[2], 
                  ymin = Value[1], ymax = Value[2]), 
              fill = dat.season$Color[1])+
    geom_rect(aes(xmin = Date[2], xmax = Date[3], 
                  ymin = Value[2], ymax = Value[3]), 
              fill = dat.season$Color[2])+
    geom_rect(aes(xmin = Date[3], xmax = Date[4], 
                  ymin = Value[3], ymax = Value[4]), 
              fill = dat.season$Color[3])+
    geom_rect(aes(xmin = Date[4], xmax = Date[5], 
                  ymin = Value[4], ymax = Value[5]), 
              fill = dat.season$Color[4])+
    geom_rect(aes(xmin = Date[5], xmax = Date[6], 
                  ymin = Value[5], ymax = Value[6]), 
              fill = dat.season$Color[5])+
    geom_rect(aes(xmin = Date[6], xmax = Date[7], 
                  ymin = Value[6], ymax = Value[7]), 
              fill = dat.season$Color[6])+
    geom_rect(aes(xmin = Date[7], xmax = Date[8], 
                  ymin = Value[7], ymax = Value[8]), 
              fill = dat.season$Color[7])+
    geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = Value)) +
    theme_bw()
```

#### The result

[image]

Comment: I wanted to have the Background coloured, ideally by using geom_rect

Comment: OK please check my updated answer.